# Running Firebase Deploy gives JSON error trying to load file

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

Getting an error when deploying to firebase. I manually edited `.firebaserc` file to add other projects.

```
$ firebase deploy --project staging --only hosting:admin
⚠  JSON error trying to load /some/path/to/.firebaserc
```

**.firebaserc**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "production": "myapp-8879",
    "staging": "myapp-c8499"
  },
  "targets": {
    "myapp-8879": {
      "admin": [
        "admin-app"
      ],
      "app": [
        "myapp-8879"
      ],
    },
    "myapp-c8499": {
      "admin": [
        "admin-app"
      ],
      "app": [
        "myapp-c8499"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To solve this problem, `JSON error trying to load /some/path/.firebaserc` you must make sure JSON format is correct.

.firebaserc

[image]

There is an extra comma, so firebase deploy will throw an error.

If you manually edit your .firebaserc on VSCODE then just change the Language Mode to JSON or use any online json formatter tool.